# Can this 12VDC Relay be used for Switching 24VDC?

Tags: voltage, relay, solid-state-relay

Can the Songle srd-12vdc-sl-c relay be used with 12VDC on its output?

On top of the relay, it writes `10A 28VDC`.

[image]

Comment: Your title, and body of the question make it very confusing.

Comment: @whatsisname Sorry, how should they be phrased?

Comment: It's not clear where the "used for 24V" from the title is involved, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Contact current has a direct affect on reliability, whereas voltage only affects open contact arc duration which is determined by load inductance. Since Relays are rated for typical usage, it would be impossible to define every application so they stick to standard automotive and truck voltage limits. Excess voltage and inductance such as from a motor could result in continuous contact arc and burnout quickly.

So in short any contact voltage less than rating is acceptable. However any current less than rating is not ok, but only specified by the  few best manufacturers. It is a well known fact by thus author, that for low currents in the mA range, relay contacts rated >2A would be unreliable unless they have a capacitive load to arc through oxide which will quickly build up on any contacts rated >2A but used for extreme light current.  Relays <2A often used in telecom often use gold plated to prevent oxidation.    This may not apply to you, but is worth remembering to use 10% of rated current with capacitive surge current or resistive current MINIMUM. But the more current above this threshold will reduce contact switching life according to a log curve as shown in spec.

The other important fact on DC current ratings for relay contacts is that Inductive loads must be derated for current. For this part, I found the spec to be 50% or 5A instead of 10A DC.

The reason for MTBF vs contact current has to do with erosion of contact material in this case Silver- Cadmium-Oxide due to I^2*R*t*N for arc duration, t , contact resistance, R (which accelerates with age) and switch cycles, N.

So in short don't worry about less voltage, but be aware of the switched current relative to specs and added experience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not look this particular part up but based on my experience 12V should be the relay winding voltage (used to activate the switch).  The other specs are the switching specs(how much voltage/current it can switch). This relay should be able to switch up to 10A at up to 250VAC or 10A at 30VDC.

Answer (score 0):

The ratings for a relay on the output side are typically the maximums the relay can handle at continuous use.

So the load side should be good up to 10A or 28/30VDC. If you put a 12v load on the switched section, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am no pro engineer, but I have designed my solar system , several switch boxes, and bus boards. I think the big question revolves around the type of switch that you are using. You have a tag stating solid state, and if that is true I would first find the schematic to the relay and that will tell all. If it is a simple mechanical relay then less voltage on through the contact points is not a big problem providing the amps are not exceeded. If solid state the specs on top are specific and should be followed, as it looks the relay is powered by 12-volt and switch 10-amps at three different voltages that will be checked by the circuit and may or may not recognize lower voltage and could possibly create a brown out situation and over heat the relay because the voltage or pressure is inadequate causing the amperage to rise. One thin to always remember is a*v=w it is absolute, and if volts drop amp rise and vice versa. the best thing to do here is to Google the relay and find manufacturers specifications, recommendations, and uses. I just did a quick Google of the part number and it jumped right out at me, so the absolute answer is easy just read it.

Here is the Google url.
https://www.google.com/search?q=srd-12vdc-sl-c+datasheet&rlz=1C1OPRB_enUS517US517&oq=sdr-12vdc-&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.16631j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8